# C# Entity Framework Devexpress GridControl Repository

Tags: c#, frameworks, devexpress, entity

My scenario like this. Now I listeletiy my data grid control. But this reengineer the grid, which can save the changes. Meanwhile all DevExpress controls. I did this just edited a column on the grid. I used a ımagecomboboxedit as respository in this column. In the indices from 0 to 10 have a much substance. I alone can not fill the grid control when it comes to select the item in the value column ımagecomboboxedit kontrolğn and most importantly, I can not handle the control grid of material that I choose from ımagecomboboxedit.

Please help me on this topic. How do I follow a different path.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is. Could you post some example code and/or re-describe your case?

Comment: I chose the short repository used imagecomboboxedit kontrolğn item gösterebilirm in how the grid control.

Comment: Are you using google translator or something similar? I am having a hard time to decipher your writings...

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I do not have sufficient knowledge of English

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not able to help you with this description... - maybe you can find someone to help you with translation, then chances are better I think.